# Get user ID via Auth::user Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to call the ID of the user where the button will only display if the Auth::user verifies the login user with the ID of 1066. 
I want to insert here:

```
 @if(Auth::check() && ($match->status == 'open' && $match->schedule < Carbon\Carbon::now() && Auth::user()->getMatchBetAmount($match->id) <= 0))
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by doing this:

```
 @if(Auth::check() && ($match->status == 'open' && $match->schedule < Carbon\Carbon::now() && Auth::user()->getMatchBetAmount($match->id) <= 0) && Auth::user()->id == 1066)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Auth::user()->id` to get currently logged in user ID.